# Block requests in lighttpd made with HTTP/1.0 and only allow HTTP/1.1

Tags: webserver, http, denial-of-service, lighttpd

I have a lighttpd web server that delivers PHP-generated webpages. This server is currently facing a lot of traffic due to a DDoS bot attack, and I am looking for a way to block or mitigate some of those.

As far as I know lighttpd offers the possibility to block requests via remote IP address, e.g. by putting

```
$HTTP["remoteip"] == "12.34.56.0/24" {
  url.access-deny = ( "" )
}
```

into `lighttpd.conf`, all requests coming from the IP range 12.34.56.0 - 12.34.56.255 would be blocked.

However, due the nature of DDoS it is not feasible to block single IP addresses or ranges, because they change quite frequently.

By examining the access log I found that most of the requests from bots seem to use the older HTTP/1.0 protocol, while most legitimate traffic uses HTTP/1.1.

So my question is: *Is there a way to block/deny all requests that come in via HTTP/1.0 (and allow those via HTTP/1.1) in lighttpd?*

I could not find such a possibility in the official [lighttpd configuration documentation](https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/docs_configuration).

Notes:

- I am aware that some legitimate traffic might also use HTTP/1.0, but it would be OK for me to block those, too.
- The bot requests do not seem to use a common pattern for user agents or HTTP referrers, so using those with a regular expression pattern does not seem to be an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of giving a solution for `lighttpd`, I would recommend you to use [fail2ban](https://www.fail2ban.org) that is present on all Unix based system. It is watching for changes in log files and parses it according to regular expression rules and in case of matching pattern (HTTP/1.0 in your case) will block it at system's firewall level which is more effective to block unwanted connections.

Also, if you are experiencing abnormal traffic where you see more malicious requests than normal requests, you can add following firewall rule to slowdown DDoS attack

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m limit --limit 20/minute --limit-burst 127 -j ACCEPT
```

If you still want to block HTTP/1.0 at `lighttpd` level, try to match HTTP protocol like that:

```
env.SERVER_PROTOCOL == "HTTP/1.0" {
  url.access-deny = ( "" )
}
```

<sup><sup>(Solution isn't tested since I switched to `nginx` a long time ago, but AFAIR it might work.)</sup></sup>

Comment: [lighttpd mod_magnet](https://wiki.lighttpd.net/Docs_ModMagnet) can match on the HTTP protocol string and lua scripts can perform arbitrary request manipulation inside lighttpd.  Still, the fail2ban and firewall solution is probably better to block attacks at the front door, before those requests reach lighttpd.